# Changing a Constant Reference Line by Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I am adding a dynamic reference line as described in the article.

https://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/changing-a-constant-reference-line-by-filter

I want to show a reference line with the average value of all four regions (2750) when the filter selects all regions (instead of only one region).

I changed the code from "ELSE NULL" to "ELSE 2750" , but it did not work.

```
ATTR(IF [Region]="West" Then 2000
ELSEIF [Region]="East" Then 5000
ELSEIF [Region]="Central" Then 1000
ELSEIF [Region]="South" Then 3000
Else 2750
END)
```

My expected result is: once I select all four regions, the reference line will show 2750. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: I have decided to modify the input data from SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another ISNULL:

```
`ATTR(IF [Region]="West" Then 2000
 ELSEIF [Region]="East" Then 5000
 ELSEIF [Region]="Central" Then 1000
 ELSEIF [Region]="South" Then 3000
 ELSE ISNULL([Region]) Then 2750
 END) `
```

If this doesnt work, use:

```
`ATTR(IF [Region]="West" Then 2000
 ELSEIF [Region]="East" Then 5000
 ELSEIF [Region]="Central" Then 1000
 ELSEIF [Region]="South" Then 3000
 ELSEIF ISNULL([Region]) Then 2750
 ELSE 0
 END)`
```